# What does 'coupling' mean? (Laser)

Tags: optics, quantum-electrodynamics, laser

I assume this question is so basic that no YT-video or paper I found answers it. But in order to understand I have to know what it refers to.

I'm talking about laser coupling to be exact. I have a 'coupler' device. What does it do with the laser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coupling is the term used to describe the coupling of laser equipment together in the same way as a  [mechanical coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling).

One such laser coupler is the laser to fiber-coupler as can be seen in [this youtube video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahDbh5UrwNc). The goal in this device is to get the laser output beam coupled as good as possible into the fiber cable.

What it does with the laser beam depends on what you are going to couple it from an to. In the example of the fiber-laser coupler, the beam is adjusted to match the acceptance angle of the fiber, the beam diameter, and to remove internal reflections from the coupling.